# Cannot get javascript innerHtml to work on WebView

Tags: javascript, android

I am using a WebView with a javaScript interface.  All I want to do is change the inner html of a span if some checkboxes are ticked.

Below is a snippet of a String I have in strings.xml.  The form will call this function onSubmit and should not continue if it does not pass.  The problem is that I can't get the innerHtml working (is returns true everytime).

This works

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">
    function pass() {
        return javaInterface.checkboxPass();
        /*
        if(passed) {
            //change the instructions
            document.getElementById(\"txtInstructions\").innerHTML = \'Loading Website...\';
        }

        return passed;
        */
    }
</script>
```

This returns true everytime

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">
    function pass() {
        var passed= javaInterface.checkboxPass();

        if(passed) {
            //change the instructions
            document.getElementById(\"txtInstructions\").innerHTML = \'Loading Website...\';
        }

        return passed;

    }
</script>
```

This is the span in the body of the document

```
<span id=\"txtInstructions\">%1$s</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you're backslash-escaping quote characters? Otherwise this is not standard HTML/javascript.

Comment: What is the code for `checkboxPass`?  If it returns an object or a string, the `if(pass)` will always evaluate to true.  For example, `if("false")` will evaluate to true as far as I know.  It will only be false if checkboxPass returns false, null, or undefined.

Comment: @tjameson javaInterface.checkboxPass() returns a boolean

Comment: @slebetman because it is stored in the XML strings file

Comment: Is this still an active question?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why the code doesn't behave like you want it to, but I can tell that you are trying to do this in a way too complicated fashion. Storing your JavaScript and HTML in an XML file seems like a genuine bad idea. I guess it is legal JavaScript, but naming a variable the same as it's parent function just seems wrong, in general you shouldn't use such scope subtleties, it's good for nothing but obfuscation.

Comment: I changed the variable name to passed but still have the same problem

Comment: I'd have to see a more complete view of your code, preferably I'd like to see it hosted on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I still think that your method is returning something that isn't strictly a boolean. I would try doing something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function pass() {
    var passed= javaInterface.checkboxPass();

    if(JSON.parse(passed)) {
        //change the instructions
        document.getElementById(\"txtInstructions\").innerHTML = \'Loading Website...\';
    }

    return passed;

}
</script>
```

This will rule out the possibility of the "boolean" being wrapped in quotes or something else lame.  If this truly is a Java interface, it probably is converting the boolean to a string.

I don't think that booleans can be passed as real boolean values, especially since javascript and java work differently under the hood. You could use eval, but it's not good practice because if it were a function, it would run it.

IE doesn't have an parse function, so you'll have to use this:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js